# Mutual intelligibility of programming languages

Tags: syntax, programming-languages

Borrowing the term from linguistics, what programming languages, if any, are mutually intelligible among them to some degree? To clarify, suppose we know programming language x, but we happen to need to read some code in language y. Is fluency or even basic knowledge of certain programming languages helpful in understanding the syntax of some other language we do not know?

Comment: C++, Java, JavaScript and quite a few others adopted some of their syntax from C.

Answer (score 0):

As someone who knows around 20 different computer languages, I can say without any hesitation that it absolutely helps. And I would say it does not in any way restrict itself to a subset of languages, but it definitely varies in degrees between certain languages.

For example, knowing Java I picked up C# without barely trying. The concepts and feel were similar enough that it was a trivial jump. However, picking up LISP, a functional programming language, was a much different process, one that required me to think differently to really grasp it. I would equate that with the difference between learning to write Spanish after knowing English, and then learning to write Chinese. The concept of a phonetic alphabet makes a big difference in the ease that one might pick it up.

And, like how many languages evolved from Latin, many computer languages have evolved from common roots like C. So, like languages, you can see the common ancestry.

Answer (score 0):

I use JavaScript and Ruby in my day to day life but I can also look at some objective-C and figure out what it's trying to do (even if I couldn't write it myself.) Generally the more Languages you know, the easier it is to learn another.

Computer languages are organized into various kinds. Much like actual languages. And if you've learned one kind, others of the same kind are easier. For example if you only speak Portuguese, you'll probably understand more Spanish than a Chinese speaker. And if you speak Chinese you'll be able to read some Japanese kanji since they originated from the same thing.

Specifically computer languages are divided into Procedural Languages (C, Fortran), Object-Oriented languages(C++, Ruby), and Functional Languages (Haskell, Closure). Of course, some languages borrow elements from several of these (JavaScript) so there are shades of grey.

tldr: Yes, knowing one language can help you understand another.